# Close current browser window and try to open another browser window using same selenium webdriver giving exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hi the following code give no such session exception in selenium.

```
WebDriver webdriver= new ChromeDriver();    
webdriver.get(appUrl);
webdriver.close();
webdriver.get(appUrl);
```

The requirement i have is open the browser, do some stuff, close it. open another browser , do some stuff. For this i am trying to use a single webdriver instance and it throws error. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It will throw error
*"org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died"*

What you need to do is create new browser instance,

```
WebDriver webdriver= new ChromeDriver();    
webdriver.get(appUrl);
webdriver.close();
webdriver= new ChromeDriver(); 
webdriver.get(appUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the [API documentation](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) tells us so:

> Close the current window, quitting the browser if it's the last window
>   currently open.

This should work (re-instantiate your driver):

```
WebDriver webdriver= new ChromeDriver();    
webdriver.get(appUrl);
webdriver.close();
webdriver= new ChromeDriver();
webdriver.get(appUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is Throwing the error because, when you are saying driver.close(); it is killing the current instance. And after killing current instance you have to create a new one. So you can user same driver to launch chrome again.

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();    
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.close();
driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of all the answers on this post i came to conclusion that if i am running a single browser for my tests the following code is the best

```
WebDriver webdriver= new ChromeDriver();    
webdriver.get(appUrl);
webdriver.quit();
webdriver= new ChromeDriver(); 
webdriver.get(appUrl);
```